# How to remount special device proc which does not exist?

Tags: linux, mount, proc

I did this:

```
root# mkdir /tmp/test && mount --bind /tmp/test/ /proc/
root# rm -rf /tmp/test
root# mount -t proc proc /proc
```

But then I ran into this:

> mount: special device proc does not exist

```
[root@srv ~]# umount /proc
umount: /proc: umount failed: No such file or directory
[root@srv ~]# umount /proc
umount: /proc: umount failed: No such file or directory
[root@srv ~]# mount -t proc proc /proc
mount: special device proc does not exist
[root@srv ~]# ls -al /proc
total 0

[root@srv ~]# uname -r
3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64
[root@srv ~]# mount -V
mount from util-linux 2.23.2 (libmount 2.23.0: selinux, debug, assert)
[root@srv ~]# umount -V
umount from util-linux 2.23.2 (libmount 2.23.0: selinux, debug, assert)
```

How can I remount `/proc`  without restarting?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? There is no such option `--bind` for umount (at least not in my system). Mounting /proc usually works if I run `mount -t proc /proc <MOUNTPOINT>`, e.g. in rescue mode when I have to chroot into a system. So in this case you would be missing a `/` in front of the second `proc`.

Comment: I typed a typo, sorry, changed

Comment: Okay, the first mount command is wrong, it should be `mount --bind /proc /tmp/test`. If you remove the bind mount `umount /tmp/test` you don't need to remount /proc, it stays mounted even if you have a second mount of proc. After the first mount command run `mount | grep proc` and then again after `umount /tmp/test`, /proc should still be mounted.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I executed the three commands I described on my Linux host. All I need is to remount the proc device to /proc.

Comment: In fact, after I executed those three commands, the /proc folder is empty.

Comment: If I don't execute the rm -rf /tmp/test command, the third command will work.

Answer (score 1):

What you did with the first mount is overlap the original `/proc`. 
Don't remove `/tmp/test` but umount it:

```
leap:~ # mount -o bind /tmp/test/ /proc/
leap:~ # mount |  grep proc
mount: failed to read mtab: No such file or directory
leap:~ # umount /proc
leap:~ # mount |  grep proc
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=23,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=13202)
```

If you deleted the directory before unmounting you have to reboot, I'm not sure but I don't think you can remount /proc from that state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Restart can solve this problem. I want to learn how to solve it without restarting.

Comment: That's why I mentioned the umount, don't delete the directory before unmounting it.

Comment: Haha, thank you, I am curious about the logic behind it.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this error message, you need to run another command first:

```
root# mkdir /tmp/test && mount --bind /tmp/test/ /proc/
root# rm -rf /tmp/test
root# umount /proc/
root# mount -t proc proc /proc
```

But you probably started with the `proc` psuedo-filesystem mounted on `/proc`.  In that case, the last command will show a new message:

```
mount: /proc: proc already mounted on /proc
```

You could avoid the new error message if you run `umount /proc/` *twice*, before trying to mount it again.  However you don't say any reason why you want to do that :-).  Probably you only want to run the first three commands above :-).  Then you can continue using the `/proc` filesystem as usual.

---

You are not allowed to run the commands you tried (on Linux).  The reason is that after you delete a directory, you are not allowed to use it as a directory.  When you try to use a deleted directory, Linux returns the error code `ENOENT`.  The description for this error code is "No such file or directory".

Technically the error code is confusing, because the directory technically still exists.  But it fits better than any of the other error codes :-).

```
# mkdir dir
# cd dir
# rmdir ../dir
# mkdir subdir
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘subdir’: No such file or directory
```

Similarly, you are not allowed to mount a filesystem on top of a deleted directory.

```
# mount --bind /proc .
mount: .: mount(2) system call failed: No such file or directory.
```

I say that the directory technically still exists, because it still has an inode number (and the inode still stores a time stamp, and a permission mode,  etc):

```
# ls -l -i -d .
5521426 drwxr-xr-x. 0 root root 0 Oct 18 13:09 .
# chmod a-x .
# ls -l -d .
drw-r--r--. 0 root root 0 Oct 18 13:09 .
```

Your `mount` command did not print the generic description of the error code: "No such file or directory".  The `mount` program tries to guess exactly what could have caused the error code.  Unfortunately, this means it sometimes guesses wrong :-).  There was no problem with "the special device proc".  The problem was the mount point `/proc`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. My environment is CentOS7 (3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64). I did have executed the three commands, but I tried to use the "umount /proc" command and the system prompts me." umount: /proc: umount failed: No such file or directory", my mount version is "mount from util-linux 2.23.2 (libmount 2.23.0: selinux, debug, assert)"

Comment: In the beginning, the pseudo file system /proc was present.

Comment: @Pdogeed wow, weird.  It seemed to work for me on Fedora 28 (mount provided by util-linux version 2.32.1, kernel 4.18.10).  You could double-check the error is in the `umount()` system call - actually probably `umount2()` - by running `strace -f umount /proc`. It sounds like you might have found a bug.

Comment: Yes, you are right. When I am in the <Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (4.4.0-132-generic) umount from util-linux 2.27.1 (libmount 2.27.0: selinux, assert, debug)> environment, the method you provide is feasible, I Just run umount /proc, the proc pseudo file system will automatically remount. I think this might be a bug.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, I have solved it, recompile util-linux at
Https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.33/, which can be solved by compiling the generated umount /proc command.

Comment: Excellent :-). I wonder if the "buggy" version of `umount` would work, if you used the `--no-canonicalize` option.

Comment: Adding the umount command with this option does not solve the problem. But from the system call, the new version of the command is very different from the old one. But my experience and technology are limited, and I can't correctly judge the difference between the logic of two commands.